# How can i get high resolusion with cordova 4.1.2？

Tags: cordova

My test phone's resolution is 1920*1080, it used to be done well.
But when I update the Cordova to version 4.1.2, I get 360 when I try:

```
alert(document.documentElement.offsetWidth)
```

I have tried some methods such as changing viewport settings but it has no use. Can anybody help me?